# UIPIckerView not showing on desired location

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a UIPickcerView placed on my Xib. when I run the app pickerView is showing on the bottom of screen, no matter where I place it on the Xib its always showing in the bottom of the screen.

Here as you can see its placed on top of screen.

[image]

But when I run the app,its on the bottom

[image]

Here is my code so far

```
func setupPIckerView(){
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.removeFromSuperview()
    countryTextField.inputView = pickerView
}

// MARK: Delegate Methods

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return "Text"
}

// MARK: Data Source Methods

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(colorPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Thanks for provinding an alternative But I want to use UIPIckerView. Is it possible to resolve the issue with UIPickerView ?

Comment: Did you try changing the frame of the UIPickcerView programatically?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting pickerView always down because you have set the pickerView as an inputView of countryTextField. Change your setupPIckerView like this

```
func setupPIckerView(){
   self.pickerView.dataSource = self
   self.pickerView.delegate = self
}
```

Add the delegate method of UITextField

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField == self.countryTextField) {
        textField.inputView = UIView()
        self.pickerView.hidden = false
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (textField == self.countryTextField) {
        self.pickerView.hidden = true
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But I want it to be presented when user tap on my textField. Its kind of selection for input. User will be presented with a list of coutries and user can select a country from them.

Comment: Then you need to handle the pickerView hide and show

Comment: Can you elaborate it please ?

Answer (score 0):

because you used the `textField`'s `inputView`, the `textField`'s `inputView` is always showing on the bottom of the screen.

If you want to show the `inputView` on other locations, you can implement a `CustomView: UIView` to replace the `inputView`, then you can show the view's location on your custom location.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIpickerview frame programatically with reference to your text field.

```
pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,textfield.frame.origin.y+20,self.view.frame.size.width,300);
```